# question regarding the pricing of Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a price difference between retrieving 15 NUMBER fields from a single document and retrieving one NUMBER field each from 15 documents at Firestore?

I am optimizing the Firestore database structure in terms of cost-efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably asking about the pricing unit called a **document read**. As its name implies, you are charged each time a document is read. So:

- if you read 15 fields from 1 document, you're charged 1 document read.
- if you read 1 field from 15 documents, you're charged 15 document reads.